# Add linker flags only to specific libraries in CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang

Say I have a final executable called exec and I need to link it with 2 shared libraries - libA and libB. For libA I would like to pass some linker flag, the other library I would prefer not to.

This is how my simplified CMakeLists.txt file looks like at the moment:

```
add_executable(exec
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(exec
    PRIVATE
    libA
    libB
)
target_link_options(exec PRIVATE "-Wl,--no-as-needed")
```

Right now CMake will treat it as if I passed --no-as-needed option to both libraries.

I want to achieve this very strict order:

```
-Wl,-no-as-needed -llibA -Wl,-as-needed -llibB
```

From what I know CMake does not guarantee that libraries will be passed to linker in the order they're written in target_link_libraries as the order can change if it results from depencencies so I cannot write:

```
target_link_libraries(exec
    PRIVATE
    "-Wl,-no-as-needed"
    libA
    "-Wl,-as-needed"
    libB
)
```

Comment: `so I cannot write` Did you try it?

Comment: Yes and for now it works, however in case dependencies will require libraries to be provided to linker in different order this could potentially break things. I might be on the wrong here of course, however I did not find anything in documentation stating otherwise.

Comment: `I did not find anything in documentation` so did you find `SHELL:`?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in the assumption that CMake does not guarantee ordering of linker flags. Additionally, duplicate entries are used only once.

To solve it, you can use [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) instead of `target_link_librares` in combination with `SHELL:` prefix. This prefix allows you to create a group of linker flags that will not change order within the group.

It will get more complicated if libA is a CMake target, in which case `target_link_libraries( exec PRIVATE libA )` will generate something more compilicated than just `-llibA`. The most straightforward solution there would be to modify definition of target `libA` to already include the flag with the `SHELL:` prefix. But this does not seem to be your case.

So the solution is:

```
target_link_options( exec PRIVATE "SHELL:-Wl,-no-as-needed -llibA" )
target_link_options( exec PRIVATE "SHELL:-Wl,-as-needed -llibB" )
```

This can generate either `-Wl,-no-as-needed -llibA -Wl,-as-needed -llibB` or `-Wl,-as-needed -llibB -Wl,-no-as-needed -llibA`.